# How do I make a batch file run strings as commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a batch file to circumvent some cmd problems on my computer, but for that I need to be able to take String user input and run it as a command.

Basically what I want to be able to do is type in a command when the batch file asks for input, and have the computer run that command, similar to python's os module (class?)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Simply assign the string to a variable, then "execute" the variable as though it was a program

eg

```
set  myvar=ECHO Hello, World!
%myvar%
```

Comment: What if I want to redirect the output of %myvar% to a file? I tried: `%myvar% > myfile.txt`, but it complains: "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: @Apteryx: Simply "escape" the `>` with a caret : `^>` This turns off the special meaning of the following character.

Comment: Worth noting the absence of quotation marks after the variable assignment. (I was trying something similar to `set myvar="ECHO Hello, World"` and it took me a while to figure this out).

Comment: I spent an hour to find this answer. If it was the first in the search...

Answer (score 8):

Use the `set /p` command to prompt for input. This command also displays a message. Example:

```
@echo off
set "command=dir"
set /p "command=type in a command: "
echo.command is: %command%
echo.press any key or ^<CTRL+C^> to abort . . .
>nul pause
%command%
```

Answer (score 4):

At its simplest, you want to use `set /p` to prompt for the command, setting an environment variable to the result, then simply expand the environment variable by itself and the OS will attempt to execute it as a command.

```
SET /P COMMAND=Command:
%COMMAND%
```

Comment: Endoro's answer is more "complete" by turning `echo off` for a cleaner output, enclosing the `set` in quotes to avoid having to escape some characters, etc, which are all good coding practice when working with batch files.  But I like minimalist code to focus on just the question asked.  Vote up or accept whichever format you prefer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the batch for loop, this works for me in the command prompt, but not the power shell:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('python -c "print('set wow=yep')"') DO set toexec=%i

C:\Users\Administrator>set toexec=set wow=yep

C:\Users\Administrator>%toexec%

C:\Users\Administrator>echo %wow%
yep
```

Answer (score -1):

this is a script to run whatever you input is this what you meant?

```
@echo off
set /p input=Command: 
%input% >>run.txt
ren run.txt run.bat
start run.bat
exit
```